How can I solve the JS code problem to make my simple project better than before?
I have made an analog and digital clock project for front-end development practice. The digital clock is running correctly, but the analog clock is not working correctly. The analog clock's minute and hour hands rotate smoothly but those two hands are jumping ahead and resetting back to the correct positions in respected seconds and minutes intervals.
Before this issue occurred I had faced another one where the minute and hour hands were not in the correct positions. After solving it the minute and hour hands both jump one minute and one hour ahead respectively (one minute more and one hour more) when the 60-second interval is completed the minute hand smoothly rotates one minute ahead but in the exact 60 seconds, it jumps one more minute ahead. In the same way, when the 60 minutes interval is done the hour hand behaves in the same way. Again the minute and hour hands reset to the correct position after 15 seconds and 15 minutes respectively.
Here are the code snippet.


const hourHand = document.getElementById('hour');
const minuteHand = document.getElementById('minute');
const secondHand = document.getElementById('second');
const digitalClock = document.getElementById('digital-clock');

// Offset variables (to correct the delay)
const offsetHours = 3; // Analog clock is 3 hours ahead
const offsetMinutes = 15; // Analog clock is 15 minutes ahead
const offsetSeconds = 15; // Analog clock is 15 seconds ahead

function updateClock() {
  const now = new Date();

  // Adjust Bangladesh time for both clocks
  const localOffset = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; // Local offset in milliseconds
  const bangladeshOffset = 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Bangladesh offset in milliseconds (GMT+6)
  const bangladeshTime = new Date(now.getTime() + localOffset + bangladeshOffset);

  // Get digital time components
  const digitalHours = bangladeshTime.getHours();
  const digitalMinutes = bangladeshTime.getMinutes();
  const digitalSeconds = bangladeshTime.getSeconds();

  // Adjust analog clock by subtracting the offset
  const correctedHours = (digitalHours - offsetHours + 24) % 24; // Ensure valid 24-hour format
  const correctedMinutes = (digitalMinutes - offsetMinutes + 60) % 60; // Ensure valid 60 minutes
  const correctedSeconds = (digitalSeconds - offsetSeconds + 60) % 60; // Ensure valid 60 seconds

  // Calculate degrees for the analog clock hands
  const hourDeg = (360 / 12) * (correctedHours % 12) + (30 / 60) * correctedMinutes;
  const minuteDeg = (360 / 60) * correctedMinutes + (6 / 60) * correctedSeconds;
  const secondDeg = (360 / 60) * correctedSeconds;

  // Apply rotation to analog clock hands
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDeg}deg)`;
  minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minuteDeg}deg)`;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDeg}deg)`;

  // Update the digital clock display
  const formattedHours = digitalHours < 10 ? `0${digitalHours}` : digitalHours;
  const formattedMinutes = digitalMinutes < 10 ? `0${digitalMinutes}` : digitalMinutes;
  const formattedSeconds = digitalSeconds < 10 ? `0${digitalSeconds}` : digitalSeconds;
  const amPm = digitalHours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  digitalClock.textContent = `${formattedHours % 12 || 12}:${formattedMinutes}:${formattedSeconds} ${amPm}`;
}

// Update the clock every 1000ms (1 second)
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

// Initialize the clock immediately
updateClock();
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f4f4, #ccc);
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 8px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0%;
  /* Ensure the hand rotates from the center */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 0.05s ease-in-out;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  /* Rotates around the base of the hand */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 0.05s ease-in-out;
}

.hour {
  width: 25%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
}

.minute {
  width: 40%;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
}

.second {
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
}

.numbers {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  transform-origin: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(calc(var(--i) * 30deg)) translateY(-140px);
}

.number:after {
  content: attr(data-number);
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--i) * -30deg));
}

.digital-clock {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
<div class="container">
  <!-- Analog Clock -->
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="numbers">
      <div class="number" style="--i: 1;" data-number="1"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 2;" data-number="2"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 3;" data-number="3"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 4;" data-number="4"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 5;" data-number="5"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 6;" data-number="6"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 7;" data-number="7"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 8;" data-number="8"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 9;" data-number="9"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 10;" data-number="10"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 11;" data-number="11"></div>
      <div class="number" style="--i: 12;" data-number="12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hand hour" id="hour"></div>
    <div class="hand minute" id="minute"></div>
    <div class="hand second" id="second"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Digital Clock -->
  <div class="digital-clock" id="digital-clock">
    00:00:00 AM
  </div>
</div>




You had problem with template literals.

It jumps when digitalSeconds = 15, so I would look at this line:  correctedSeconds = (digitalSeconds - offsetSeconds + 60) % 60

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Are you at anytime leaving the page like going to another TAB? All browsers will throttle timers like setTimeout() and setInterval() should the page become no longer visible (eg. tabbing over to somewhere else).

the display problem you encounter with the offset of the hands is due to the difference between the initial and final positions.
If this difference is negative the rotation is done in the opposite direction, which happens at the end of a complete turn and you have this unpleasant graphic glitch where your hand turns backwards in a jerky manner.
the solution is to always increase the rotation angle, but this implies gaining turns, especially for the second hand...
So the idea here is to reset this degree counter as close as possible to zero (the setInterval() method does not guarantee its duration) but deactivating the animation to replace it in the same place; here using the transitionOFF class.
PS: you declare the class hand twice in your CSS


const
  hand = 
    [ { elm: document.querySelector('.hand.hour'),   movDeg: 360/12, val: 0 } 
    , { elm: document.querySelector('.hand.minute'), movDeg: 360/60, val: 0 } 
    , { elm: document.querySelector('.hand.second'), movDeg: 360/60, val: 0 }
    ] 
, digitalClock = document.querySelector('#digital-clock')
, updateClock  =_=>
    {
    let 
      nowTimeAmPm = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeZone:  'Asia/Dhaka' })
    , [ h, m, s ] = nowTimeAmPm.match(/\d+/g).map((v,i)=> ((Number(v) * hand[i].movDeg) % 360) )
      ;
    digitalClock.textContent = nowTimeAmPm
      ;
    [ h, m, s ].forEach( (Xdeg,i) =>
      {
      if (hand[i].val === Xdeg) return;
      let pos = ( hand[i].val < Xdeg ) ? Xdeg : (Xdeg + 360);

      hand[i].elm.style.transform = `rotate(${pos}deg)`;

      if ( hand[i].val < Xdeg )
        hand[i].val = Xdeg;
      else                   // avoid a transition rotation break at 360°
        {
        setTimeout(() => 
          {
          hand[i].elm.classList.add('transitionOFF');
          hand[i].val                 = Xdeg;
          hand[i].elm.style.transform = `rotate(${Xdeg}deg)`; // set to a correct value.
          setTimeout(()=>
            { 
            hand[i].elm.classList.remove('transitionOFF'); 
            }, 20 );
          }, 60 ); // 0.06s === 60ms -> after the previous 0.5s move transition
        }
      })
    };

updateClock();                   // Initialize the clock immediately
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
body {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items     : center;
  height          : 100vh;
  margin          : 0;
  background      : linear-gradient(to bottom, #3bbddd, #4d6686);
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
.container {
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items    : center;
  }
.analog-clock {
  position      : relative;
  --szClock     : 350px;
  width         : var(--szClock);
  height        : var(--szClock);
  border        : 8px solid #142029;
  border-radius : 50%;
  background    : #a6c3e7;
  background    : #b0caeb;
  box-shadow    : 0 4px 15px #610e0e7a;
  color         : #111e27;
  text-shadow   : 0px 1px 0px #ffffff4d, 0px -1px 0px #000000b3;
  }
.analog-clock h2 {
  margin      : 0;
  position    : absolute;
  top         : 63%;
  width       : 100%;
  color       : #244258;
  text-align  : center;
  }
.center {
  position      : absolute;
  width         : 12px;
  height        : 12px;
  background    : black;
  border-radius : 50%;
  top           : 50%;
  left          : 50%;
  transform     : translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
.hand {
  position         : absolute;
  bottom           : 50%;
  width            : 0;
  transform-origin : bottom center;
  border           : 0 solid #000c; /*   border-color : #081824; */
  transition       : transform 0.05s ease-in-out; 
  --wBorder        : 6px;
  left               : calc(50% - var(--wBorder));
  height             : 30%;
  border-right-width : var(--wBorder);
  border-left-width  : var(--wBorder);
  border-radius      : var(--wBorder);
  }
.hand.transitionOFF {
  transition       : none !important;
  }
.minute {
  --wBorder    : 4px;
  height       : 39%;
  }
.second {
  --wBorder    : 2px;
  height       : calc( var(--szClock) * .395 );
  border-color : crimson;
  }
.hour-numbers {
  position      : absolute;
  width         : 100%;
  height        : 100%;
  counter-reset : hourNum;
  font-weight   : bold;
  font-size     : 1.6em;
  text-align    : center;
  line-height   : 40px;
  }
.hour-numbers > div {
  position          : absolute;
  width             : 40px;
  height            : 40px;
  transform-origin  : center;
  top               : 50%;
  left              : 50%;
  transform         : translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(calc(var(--i) * 30deg)) translateY(-154px);
  counter-increment : hourNum;
  }
.hour-numbers > div::after {
  content   : counter(hourNum, upper-roman ); 
  display   : block;
  transform : rotate(calc(var(--i) * -30deg));
  }
#digital-clock {
  margin-top    : 20px;
  font-size     : 2em;
  font-weight   : bold;
  color         : black;
  text-align    : center;
  background    : white;
  padding       : 10px 20px;
  border-radius : 10px;
  box-shadow    : 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
<div class="container">
  <div class="analog-clock">
    <h2>Bangladesh<br><small>(Asia/Dhaka)</small></h2>
    <div class="hour-numbers">
      <div style="--i: 1;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 2;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 3;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 4;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 5;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 6;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 7;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 8;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 9;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 10;" ></div>
      <div style="--i: 11;" ></div>
      <div style="--i: 12;" ></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="hand hour"   ></div> 
    <div class="hand minute" ></div> 
    <div class="hand second" ></div> 
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="digital-clock"> 00:00:00 AM </div>
</div>




First version, without transition in the movement of the hands
const 
  hourHand     = document.querySelector('.hand.hour')
, minuteHand   = document.querySelector('.hand.minute')
, secondHand   = document.querySelector('.hand.second')
, digitalClock = document.querySelector('#digital-clock')
, hmsDeg       = [ 360/12, 360/60, 360/60 ]
, updateClock  =_=>
  {
  let 
    now         = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeZone:  'Asia/Dhaka' })
  , [ h, m, s ] = now.match(/\d+/g).map((v,i)=> Number(v) * hmsDeg[i])
    ;
  h %= 360;
  digitalClock.textContent = now;
  hourHand  .style.transform  = `rotate(${h}deg)`;
  minuteHand.style.transform  = `rotate(${m}deg)`;
  secondHand.style.transform  = `rotate(${s}deg)`;
  };

updateClock();  // Initialize the clock immediately
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

demo:


const 
  hourHand     = document.querySelector('.hand.hour')
, minuteHand   = document.querySelector('.hand.minute')
, secondHand   = document.querySelector('.hand.second')
, digitalClock = document.querySelector('#digital-clock')
, hmsDeg       = [ 360/12, 360/60, 360/60 ]
, updateClock  =_=>
  {
  let 
    now         = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeZone:  'Asia/Dhaka' })
  , [ h, m, s ] = now.match(/\d+/g).map((v,i)=> Number(v) * hmsDeg[i])
    ;
  h %= 360;
  digitalClock.textContent = now;
  hourHand  .style.transform  = `rotate(${h}deg)`;
  minuteHand.style.transform  = `rotate(${m}deg)`;
  secondHand.style.transform  = `rotate(${s}deg)`;
  };

updateClock();  // Initialize the clock immediately
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
body {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items     : center;
  height          : 100vh;
  margin          : 0;
  background      : linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f4f4, #ccc);
  font-family     : 'Arial', sans-serif;
  }
.container {
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items    : center;
  }
.analog-clock {
  position      : relative;
  --szClock     : 350px;
  width         : var(--szClock);
  height        : var(--szClock);
  border        : 8px solid black;
  border-radius : 50%;
  background    : white;
  box-shadow    : 0 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
.center {
  position      : absolute;
  width         : 12px;
  height        : 12px;
  background    : black;
  border-radius : 50%;
  top           : 50%;
  left          : 50%;
  transform     : translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
.hand {
  position         : absolute;
  bottom           : 50%;
  width            : 0;
  transform-origin : bottom center;
  border           : 0 solid black;
  }
.hour {
  left               : calc(50% - 3px);
  height             : 25%;
  border-right-width : 3px;
  border-left-width  : 3px;
  }
.minute {
  left               : calc(50% - 2px);
  height             : 36%;
  border-right-width : 2px;
  border-left-width  : 2px;
  border-color       : darkblue;
  }
.second {
  left               : calc(50% - 1px);
  height             : 38%;
  border-right-width : 1px;
  border-left-width  : 1px;
  border-color       : crimson;
  }
.hour-numbers {
  position      : absolute;
  width         : 100%;
  height        : 100%;
  counter-reset : hourNum;
  color         : black;
  font-weight   : bold;
  font-size     : 1.2em;
  text-align    : center;
  line-height   : 40px;
  }
.hour-numbers > div {
  position          : absolute;
  width             : 40px;
  height            : 40px;
  transform-origin  : center;
  top               : 50%;
  left              : 50%;
  transform         : translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(calc(var(--i) * 30deg)) translateY(-140px);
  counter-increment : hourNum;
  }
.hour-numbers > div::after {
  content   : counter(hourNum);
  display   : block;
  transform : rotate(calc(var(--i) * -30deg));
  }
#digital-clock {
  margin-top    : 20px;
  font-size     : 2em;
  font-weight   : bold;
  color         : black;
  text-align    : center;
  background    : white;
  padding       : 10px 20px;
  border-radius : 10px;
  box-shadow    : 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
<div class="container">
  <div class="analog-clock">
    <div class="hour-numbers">
      <div style="--i: 1;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 2;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 3;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 4;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 5;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 6;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 7;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 8;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 9;"  ></div>
      <div style="--i: 10;" ></div>
      <div style="--i: 11;" ></div>
      <div style="--i: 12;" ></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="hand hour" ></div> 
    <div class="hand minute"></div> 
    <div class="hand second"></div> 
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="digital-clock"> 00:00:00 AM </div>
</div> 



